# Apache Http Client slower than browser

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

**Disclaimer**: I know that this question has duplicates ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046424/http-post-requests-using-httpclient-take-2-seconds-why), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451687/http-requests-with-httpclient-too-slow), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239188/apache-http-client-slower-than-browser-download?rq=1)), BUT:

- I tried all the answers and it doesn't solve the problem (I searched not only in SO)
- I provide the full internal log of http client, so experienced users can
  analize and comment it.
- Those questions are old (more than a year), many things has been changed.

---

I'm trying to get content from this URL:
https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries

Mac OS Chrome browser gets the content in around **70-100** ms (I look at dev-tools Network tab), but my code with apache http client 4.5.2 gets it in **180-200** ms.
Also I have a code with ([kevinsawicki-http-request](http://kevinsawicki.github.io/http-request/)) library, witch gets this page in **70-100** ms (like in browser).
This difference is critical for me, and (I think) for many other devs, who asked similar questions.

My code:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES)
        .setSocketTimeout(60000)
        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
        .build();
SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
        .setSoKeepAlive(false) //true - no differences in request time
        .setTcpNoDelay(true)
        .build();
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connManager.setMaxTotal(50);
connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
        .setConnectionManager(connManager)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36")
        .build();

//1
long t11 = System.currentTimeMillis();
try(CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries"))) {
    code1 = response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}
long t12 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long reqTime1 = t12 - t11;
//2
long t21 = System.currentTimeMillis();
try(CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries"))) {
    code2 = response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}
long t22 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long reqTime2 = t22 - t21;
//3
long t31 = System.currentTimeMillis();
try(CloseableHttpResponse response3 = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries"))) {
    code3 = response3.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}
long t32 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long reqTime3 = t32 - t31;

log.trace("reqTime1: {}", reqTime1);
log.trace("reqTime2: {}", reqTime2);
log.trace("reqTime3: {}", reqTime3);
```

This prints:

```
reqTime1: 198 
reqTime2: 168 
reqTime3: 160
```

(all 3 requests return 200 http code)

I have JVM options:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/my/keyStore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=my_password
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR
```

(vk.com certificate is added in my keyStore.jks)

Here is the internal log of http-client

```
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:411 MSK [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:412 MSK [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:413 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:413 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 6][route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:413 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://api.vk.com:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:414 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to api.vk.com/87.240.165.75:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:414 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to api.vk.com/87.240.165.75:443 with timeout 5000
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:494 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:495 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:495 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:641 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:642 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:642 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:642 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.vk.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:642 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.vk.com, vk.com]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:642 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2, OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:643 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 172.20.10.2:55317<->87.240.165.75:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:643 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-6: set socket timeout to 60000
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:643 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request GET /method/database.getCountries HTTP/1.1
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:643 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:644 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:644 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 >> GET /method/database.getCountries HTTP/1.1
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:644 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 >> Host: api.vk.com
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:644 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:645 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 >> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:645 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:725 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:725 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Server: Apache
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:726 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 11:54:35 GMT
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:726 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:726 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Content-Length: 286
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:727 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Connection: keep-alive
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:727 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << X-Powered-By: PHP/3.7212
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:727 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Set-Cookie: remixlang=0; expires=Sun, 05 Nov 2017 18:31:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:727 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Pragma: no-cache
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:728 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Cache-control: no-store
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:728 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-6 << Content-Encoding: gzip
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:728 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:729 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-6: Close connection
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:730 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:730 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 6][route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:730 MSK [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:731 MSK [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:731 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:731 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 7][route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:731 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://api.vk.com:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:732 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to api.vk.com/87.240.165.75:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:732 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to api.vk.com/87.240.165.75:443 with timeout 5000
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:786 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:787 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:787 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:909 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:910 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:910 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:910 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.vk.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:911 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.vk.com, vk.com]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:911 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2, OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:911 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 172.20.10.2:55318<->87.240.165.75:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:912 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-7: set socket timeout to 60000
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:912 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request GET /method/database.getCountries HTTP/1.1
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:912 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:913 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:913 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 >> GET /method/database.getCountries HTTP/1.1
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:913 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 >> Host: api.vk.com
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:913 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:914 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 >> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:914 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:989 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:989 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Server: Apache
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:990 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 11:54:35 GMT
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:990 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:990 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Content-Length: 286
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:990 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Connection: keep-alive
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:991 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << X-Powered-By: PHP/3.7212
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:991 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Set-Cookie: remixlang=0; expires=Wed, 08 Nov 2017 21:16:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:991 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Pragma: no-cache
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:991 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Cache-control: no-store
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:992 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-7 << Content-Encoding: gzip
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:992 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:992 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-7: Close connection
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:993 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:993 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 7][route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:994 MSK [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:994 MSK [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:994 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:995 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 8][route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 50]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:995 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://api.vk.com:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:996 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to api.vk.com/87.240.165.75:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:35:996 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to api.vk.com/87.240.165.75:443 with timeout 5000
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:050 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:050 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:050 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:117 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:118 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:118 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:118 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.vk.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:118 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.vk.com, vk.com]
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:118 MSK [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2, OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:119 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 172.20.10.2:55331<->87.240.165.75:443
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:119 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-8: set socket timeout to 60000
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:119 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request GET /method/database.getCountries HTTP/1.1
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:119 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:119 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:120 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 >> GET /method/database.getCountries HTTP/1.1
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:120 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 >> Host: api.vk.com
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:120 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:120 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 >> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:120 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:188 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:189 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Server: Apache
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:189 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 11:54:36 GMT
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:189 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:189 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Content-Length: 286
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:190 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Connection: keep-alive
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:190 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << X-Powered-By: PHP/3.7212
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:190 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Set-Cookie: remixlang=0; expires=Thu, 16 Nov 2017 00:20:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:190 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Pragma: no-cache
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:190 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Cache-control: no-store
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:190 MSK [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-8 << Content-Encoding: gzip
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:191 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:191 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-8: Close connection
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:192 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:192 MSK [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 8][route: {s}->https://api.vk.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 50]
[14:54:36.193] TRACE [proliker.utils.TestService.hc(TestService.java:300)]: reqTime1:    319 
[14:54:36.193] TRACE [proliker.utils.TestService.hc(TestService.java:301)]: reqTime2:    264 
[14:54:36.194] TRACE [proliker.utils.TestService.hc(TestService.java:302)]: reqTime3:    198
```

Of course, the above tests were performed with internal logging turned OFF because it adds additional ~50 ms to each request.

I have read ALL apache http-client site docs thrice, I have no idea where to look and where I have mistake. I hope so much, that some geek can help me increase request speed.

Comment: if you add this disclaimer, please link the duplicates you already tried

Comment: Do you intentionally make HttpClient to NOT re-use connections? If you do, that would certainly explain the difference with http-request or any other library based on HttpUrlConnection

Comment: @oleg no, I dont do that intentionally, why you think so?

Comment: I tried your code with and without httpClient.setUserAgent and response took around 200ms and 90 ms respectively for the second and third attempt(first was around 300-should be ssl handshake). May be its worth a look.

Comment: @jay I dont see any diferences on my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:191 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:191 MSK [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-8: Close connection
[err] 2016/11/11 14:54:36:192 MSK [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
```

If this is not intentional then the simplest way to make HttpClient faster is by re-using connections (especially when using SSL/TLS transport security).

Always make sure that response content has been fully consumed (by reading from the content stream until end of the stream or by closing the stream).

```
try(CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries"))) {
    int code1 = response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    EntityUtils.consume(response1.getEntity());
}
```

Comment: didnt know, that it is critical to recieve(read) response body (I wanted to use it, but for speed tests deleted that code), now I get: **207** (ssl handshake), **80**, **76** ms, thank you very much!